# Unhandled rejection from Google Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, promise, google-cloud-platform

I am using google cloud function to handle data's. And in one of my function, i am doing nested .then's.

The problem is, everything works find, but i am getting error of "Unhandled rejection" in function log.

I don't know what, mistake i am doing. This is my cloud function code :

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const rp = require('request-promise');

module.exports = function(req, res) {

const phone = String(req.body.phone).replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
const amount = parseInt(req.body.amount);
const couponCodeName = (req.body.couponCodeName);
const couponUsage = parseInt(req.body.couponUsage);
const usersCouponUsage = parseInt(req.body.usersCouponUsage);
const finalAddress = (req.body.finalAddress);
const planName = (req.body.planName);
const saveThisAddress = (req.body.saveThisAddress);
const orderNumber = (req.body.orderNumber);

const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri:`https://....`,
    body: {
        amount
    },
    json: true
};

return admin.auth().getUser(phone)
        .then(userRecord => {
            return rp(options)
        })
        .then((orderResponse) => {
            return admin.database().ref('trans/'+ phone)
                .push({ amount: orderResponse.amount })
            })
        .then(() => {
            return admin.database().ref('ordersOfUsers/'+ phone)
                .push({ amount })
        })
        .then(() => { 
            return saveThisAddress === true ? 
                admin.database().ref('SavedAddress/'+phone)
                    .push({address: finalAddress}) : null
        })
        .then(() => {
            return admin.database().ref('delivery/'+phone+'/'+orderNumber)
                .set({ plan: planName === "" ? "Single Day Plan" : planName, delivered: false}, () => {
                    res.status(200).send({ success:true })
                })
        })
        .then(() => {
            return couponCodeName === "" ? null : 
                admin.database().ref(`couponCodes/${couponCodeName}`)
                    .update({couponUsage: couponUsage + 1 })
        })
        .then(() => {
            return usersCouponUsage === "" ? null : 
                admin.database().ref(`couponUsage/${phone}`)
                    .update({ [couponCodeName]: usersCouponUsage + 1 })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(422).send({ error: err })
        })    
    .catch((err) => {
       res.status(422).send({error: err });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code already has return statement inside promise(except in the catch block). So may be removing the return from *return admin.auth().getUser(phone)* can resolve your error.

Comment: Actually, the problem is with the last two .then blocks, they are throwing those errors ! And, now i am suspecting that, am i correctly chained then's ? As , i am not returning anything from previous .then ( After 3rd .then ), theoretically its wrong ?